# Controlling the mouse on the desktop with pywinauto

Tags: mouse, desktop, pywinauto

I am attempting to take control of mouse events on the desktop using pywinauto.  Specifically, I am looking to make different applications active by sending a mouse click to their windows, and ideally to be able to move windows with well known title bar coordinates around.

I've tried doing app.connect_() calls to both "explorer" and "dwm" but with the exception of a DialogWrapper with the class "Progman" I've had no joy.  Searching about with SWAPY has yielded similarly poor results.

I'm not a Windows programmer so I hope I'm missing something fairly obvious here.  Any hints would be well received.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about "dwm", but "explorer" (Windows explorer) should be automated easily with pywinauto. Strange, even if pywinauto can not get/control a window's elements it perfectly detects the window title/Class & coordinates

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure why but that was the bit clarity I needed.  Following that path I found my mistake was using Click() instead of ClickInput() with the Progman element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is some code that will click on the desktop at (900, 50) using pywinauto.

Note that using ClickInput() rather than Click() is important.

---

```
import pywinauto.application

app = pywinauto.application.Application()
comapp = app.connect_(path = "explorer")

for i in comapp.windows_():
    if "Progman" == i.FriendlyClassName():
        i.ClickInput(coords=(900, 50))
```